# Tkinter - selenium: app not responding after clicking run

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter

Hello Guys I create app by tkinter and script by selenium.

After click button my app GUI in Not Responding.

this is the code to run selenium script and threading but not orking'':

```
def run_script(self):

    unittest.main(run)

def run_threading(self):

    t = threading.Thread(target=self.run_script())
    t.start()
```

[image]

Comment: Why is this tagged `tkinter`? There's no tkinter code in the question, only Qt code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't add Qt code

Comment: `target=self.run_script()` means it runs `self.run_script()` _immediately_ in the current thread. The result (`None`) is then passed to the thread.